# CEWP won't allow text to be edited

Tags: permissions, content-editor-web-part, editing-menu

Recently, I imported a CEWP on my site from another. For some reason, no other user can edit the text but me, even though they have Design permissions to edit it.

I've checked the permissions for the page the web part is on, and everything seems to be in order. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Is the page exclusively checkout to you assuming you have greater level access than the other users ?

Comment: @Moss-Farmer Yes, I have greater level access. The page is not checked out to me exclusively, however. Other users can check out the page, but they just can't edit the CEWP.